# Can I add space without a v-for?

Tags: vue.js

```
<img :src="item" v-for="item in images" />space
```

how to add a space after the /> ?

I have to do it.

Comment: To create extra spaces before, after, or in-between your text, use the &nbsp; (non-breaking space) extended HTML character.

https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001662.htm

Comment: Are you asking how to put a space character between the images in the generated HTML?

Comment: @skirtleyes.the generated html is according v-for.and how to add space character between img?

Comment: Would a non-breaking space or margin be sufficient or does it have to be a normal space character? Does it have to be exactly one space or would the usual HTML white-space collapsing rules allow for multiple spaces? Difficult to know what the constraints on the problem are without knowing *why* you need a space.

Comment: @skirtle since text-align:justify;needs a space,if there is no space it can not justify.

Comment: why do you have to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with you'll need to wrap the image and space in a `<template>`. But it's a bit more complicated than that because Vue strips out spaces in various circumstances.

Here's one way you could do it, using `{{ ' ' }}` to force the space to be retained:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data () {
    return {
      images: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  background: #ddd;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 200px;
}

img {
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template v-for="item in images">
    <img src="https://vuejs.org/images/logo.png">
    {{ ' ' }}
  </template>
</div>
```

A dummy element, like a `<span>`, could also be used instead of the `{{ ' ' }}`.

You may want to consider using flex-box instead of `text-align: justify`.

Comment: awesome .why can't I thought of this.

Comment: Buy the way,can I ask you anthoer questions?

Comment: @newprogrammer If it doesn't relate directly to my answer then you should post it as a separate SO question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60377049/can-i-use-vue-in-a-single-page-without-vue-cli-and-nodejs @skirtle