# Can I use vue in a single Page without vue-cli and nodejs?

Tags: vue.js

If there is a hello.vue and I want to use it in index.html but there is not vue-cli and nodejs.

I do know how to use vue.js but do not know how to use the vue'scomponent if I have a hello.vue.

Do not I say it clearly? please do not tell me how to  thank you.

how to use it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You just need to import Vue from CDN.

For production:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11"></script>
```

For development: (gives you full warnings and debug mode)

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Then you can just add a `script` tag and create a Vue instance.

```js
window.app = new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

For more information visit the official [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html).

Comment: I mean use vue components without cli and nodejs,I do use the vue.js

Comment: You can. But its limited. You can just create your components using `Vue.component()`.